# Linq tree for nested Expression<Func<>> - exists(select*...)

Tags: c#, sql, linq

atm im writting generic filter module in my app.
I have problem with creating proper Expression>. I general SQL query look like:

```
SELECT distinct ROW_NUMBER
FROM dbo.VIEW_ITEM item
WHERE CODE ='MyName'
  AND EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM dbo.VIEW_ITEM
              WHERE ROW_NUMBER = item.ROW_NUMBER
                AND CODE='MyName' 
                AND (COL_NUMBER=1 AND DISPLAY='UserName')) 
  AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM VIEW_ITEM
              WHERE ROW_NUMBER = item.ROW_NUMBER
              AND CODE='MyName'
              AND (COL_NUMBER=3 and DISPLAY='2261'))
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER
```

This is (in my opinion) best way to get all records I need. I **can not** use join option because im checking in my **AND EXISTS** same table as in main query.

So my linq look like:

```
dboMVI.Where(mvi => mvi.Code == "MyCode")
    .Where(mvi => dboMVI.Where(innerMvi => innerMvi.RowNumber == mvi.RowNumber && innerMvi.Code == "MyCode" && innerMvi.ColNumber == 1 && innerMvi.Display == "UserName").Any())
    .Where(mvi => dboMVI.Where(innerMvi => innerMvi.RowNumber == mvi.RowNumber && innerMvi.Code == "MyCode" && innerMvi.ColNumber == 3 && innerMvi.Display == "2261").Any())
    .Select(mvi => mvi.RowNumber)
    .OrderBy(rn => rn)
    .Distinct();
```

That should return me all Rows nnumbers that passed my filtering.
Im managed to create Expression but im sure there is better way to make it more generic and put this in my filtering module not in service from where im passing it to DbContext.

```
Expression<Func<ViewItem, bool>> filter =mvi =>
 dboMVI.Where(innerMvi => innerMvi.RowNumber == mvi.RowNumber 
&& innerMvi.Code == "MyCode" && innerMvi.ColNumber == 3 && 
innerMvi.Display == "2261").Any()
```

And For second filter:

```
Expression<Func<ViewItem, bool>> filter =mvi =>
     dboMVI.Where(innerMvi => innerMvi.RowNumber == mvi.RowNumber 
    && innerMvi.Code == "MyCode" && innerMvi.ColNumber == 1 && 
    innerMvi.Display == "UserName").Any()
```

My question is how I can create generic Expression tree for this LINQ query?

I could not find anywhere example of creating such tree.
I found example of passing arguments in join statement.
But **in my case im passing from main query number of current row and in subquery its checked if for this specific row any conditions are meet or not**.

---

EDIT: After some comments i noticed i did mistake in rewritting querys from real values to demo. Srry for that hope its fixed now:)
In general its working solution just looking for better way.

---

EDIT2:
What is my problem here:

im trying to generate from LINQ SQL query that can be consume by EF Core.
in my SQL in using AND EXISTS where in body im referring to same table as in main query. What more in sub query im using ROW_NUMBER from main query.
What is my problem? I dont know how to create expression func (responsible for my sub query) because I dont know how to pass into it my current ROW_NUMBER that im checking. I know how to make expression tree for easy examples. But there I have constant in my body fe int or string . But in this case my const is changing every time to different value so it can not be hard coded.

### Answer

I managed to resolve this issue. First of all had to simplify linq query.

```
dboMVI.Where(mvi => mvi.Code == "MyCode")
.Where(mvi => dboMVI.Any(innerMvi => innerMvi.RowNumber == mvi.RowNumber && innerMvi.Code == "MyCode" && innerMvi.ColNumber == 1 && innerMvi.Display == "UserName"))
.Where(mvi => dboMVI.Any(innerMvi => innerMvi.RowNumber == mvi.RowNumber && innerMvi.Code == "MyCode" && innerMvi.ColNumber == 3 && innerMvi.Display == "2261"))
.Select(mvi => mvi.RowNumber)
.OrderBy(rn => rn)
.Distinct()
```

Than had to create Expression tree for elements inside Any expression:

```
IQueryable<MaterializedViewItem> MyDtoList = Enumerable.Empty<MaterializedViewItem>().AsQueryable();
        var insideProperty = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MaterializedViewItem), "mviAny");
        var baseProperty = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MaterializedViewItem), "mviBaseAny");

        MemberExpression condition0Code = Expression.Property(baseProperty, "MvCode");
        ConstantExpression condition0CodeValue = Expression.Constant("ARAPP");
        var condition0 = Expression.Equal(condition0Code, condition0CodeValue);
        var predicateFirstElement = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(condition0, baseProperty);

        MemberExpression conditionACode = Expression.Property(insideProperty, "MvCode");
        ConstantExpression conditionACodeValue = Expression.Constant("MyCode");
        var conditionA = Expression.Equal(conditionACode, conditionACodeValue);

        MemberExpression conditionACol = Expression.Property(insideProperty, "ColNumber");
        ConstantExpression conditionAColValue = Expression.Constant((byte)1);
        var conditionB = Expression.Equal(conditionACol, conditionAColValue);

        MemberExpression conditionDisplay = Expression.Property(insideProperty, "ValueDisplay");
        ConstantExpression conditionDisplayValue = Expression.Constant("UserName");
        var conditionC = Expression.Equal(conditionDisplay, conditionDisplayValue);

        MemberExpression conditionRow = Expression.Property(insideProperty, "RowNumber");
        var newValueToCompare = Expression.PropertyOrField(baseProperty, "RowNumber");
        ConstantExpression conditionRowValue = Expression.Constant(0);
        var conditionD = Expression.Equal(conditionRow, newValueToCompare);

        var condition = Expression.AndAlso(conditionA, conditionB);
        var condition2 = Expression.AndAlso(conditionC, conditionD);
        var condition3 = Expression.AndAlso(condition, condition2);

        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<MaterializedViewItem, bool>>(condition3, insideProperty);

        var callCondtions = BuildAny<MaterializedViewItem>(predicate, MyDtoList.Expression);
        var myPredicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(callCondtions, baseProperty);

        MemberExpression conditionCol2 = Expression.Property(insideProperty, "ColNumber");
        ConstantExpression conditionCol2Value = Expression.Constant((byte)3);
        var conditionE = Expression.Equal(conditionCol2, conditionCol2Value);

        MemberExpression conditionColDisplay2 = Expression.Property(insideProperty, "ValueDisplay");
        ConstantExpression conditionColDisplay2Value = Expression.Constant("2261");
        var conditionF = Expression.Equal(conditionColDisplay2, conditionColDisplay2Value);
        var condition22 = Expression.AndAlso(conditionA, conditionD);
        var condition23 = Expression.AndAlso(conditionE, conditionF);
        var condition2Final = Expression.AndAlso(condition22, condition23);
        var predicate2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(condition2Final, insideProperty);

        var callCondtions2 = BuildAny<T>(predicate2, MyDtoList.Expression);
```

Neede extra function to build for me final Any with all parameters

```
public static Expression BuildAny<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Expression expression)
    {
        var overload = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(method => method.Name == "Any" && method.GetParameters().Count() == 2);
        var specificMethod = overload.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));

        var call = Expression.Call(
            specificMethod,
            expression,
            predicate);

        return call;
    }
```

What is important to remember we are building IQueryable based on temporaty object. Later it has to replaced with real db table. It can be done with:

```
IQueryable<T> queryList = this.DbSet;
        var filtersForDbSet = ExpressionTreeConstantReplacer.CopyAndReplace<DbSet<T>, T>(condition, typeof(EnumerableQuery<T>), this.DbSet);
        class ExpressionTreeConstantReplacer
            {
                internal static Expression<Func<T2, bool>> CopyAndReplace<T, T2>(Expression<Func<T2, bool>> expression, Type originalType, T replacementConstant)
                {
                    var modifier = new ExpressionTreeConstantReplacer<T>(originalType, replacementConstant);
                    var newLambda = modifier.Visit(expression) as LambdaExpression;

                    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T2, bool>>(newLambda.Body, newLambda.Parameters.FirstOrDefault());
                }
        }
```

and

```
        class ExpressionTreeConstantReplacer<T> : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        Type originalType;
        T replacementConstant;

        internal ExpressionTreeConstantReplacer(Type originalType, T replacementConstant)
        {
            this.originalType = originalType;
            this.replacementConstant = replacementConstant;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression c)
        {
            return c.Type == originalType ? Expression.Constant(replacementConstant) : c;
        }
    }
```

If anyone will have similar problem in expression tree. Query is build same as in normal query. To pass some vale from main expression to inside expression you have to just show that you are comparing them as:

```
MemberExpression conditionRow = Expression.Property(insideProperty, "RowNumber");
        var newValueToCompare = Expression.PropertyOrField(baseProperty, "RowNumber");
        var conditionD = Expression.Equal(conditionRow, newValueToCompare
```

Comment: Why are you calling `Where` three times in a row? AND nesting more `Where`'s in the filter?

Comment: You're using `mvi.Code = "MyCode"` instead of `mvi.Code == "MyCode"`!

Comment: Why are you using `ValueDisplay` in the LINQ but `DISPLAY` in the SQL?

Comment: Your query can be simplified this way: `SELECT distinct ROW_NUMBER
FROM dbo.VIEW_ITEM item
WHERE CODE ='MyName'AND COL_NUMBER IN(1, 3) AND DISPLAY IN ('UserName', '2261')
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER`

Comment: What part of the query are you trying to generalize and what's the issue of doing it? Creating and passing `Expression<Func<ViewItem, bool>> filter` from outside w/o having access to `dboMVI`?

Comment: @IvanStoev I want to create generic filter that build only from passed filters base on Binary expression. Hardcoding some filters is not my target. Also i would have to add ref to my DbContext in my FilterCreator. I preffer to pass only Expression<Func<T,bool>> to my this.dbContext.Where(expression).

Comment: May be you should update the post with some example of the desired design, e.g. method signatures, arguments etc. and specifying which part doesn't work. I see no problem of composing filter from passed `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` - there are many examples how you can do `Or`, `And` etc., so your  problem seems to be different (and still unclear to me).

Comment: @IvanStoev, I added extra comment please check if it's now more clearly

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned in the comment to the question, your query can be simpliefied.

**[Initial note]**

Accordingly to the discussion in comments, i think, your query can be still improved.

**[Version #1]** - first look

```
SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER
FROM dbo.VIEW_ITEM item
WHERE CODE ='MyName'AND COL_NUMBER IN(1, 3) AND DISPLAY IN ('UserName', '2261')
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER
```

Based on your SQL query, a Linq version may look like:

```
int[] nums = {1, 3};
string[] disp = {"UserName", "2261"}; 

var result = dboMVI
    .Where(mvi=> mvi.Code == 'MyName' && 
        nums.Any(n=> n.Contains(mvi.ColNumber)) &&
        disp.Any(d=> d.Contains(mvi.Display))
    .OrderBy(x=>x.RowNumber)
    .Select(x=>.RowNumber);
```

In case when above query does not meet your criteria, you'd try to combine the conditions with parentheses:

**[Version #2]** - second look

```
SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER
FROM dbo.VIEW_ITEM item
WHERE (CODE ='MyName'AND COL_NUMBER IN(1, 3)) AND 
    (CODE ='MyName' AND DISPLAY IN ('UserName', '2261'))
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER
```

A Linq equivalent:

```
var result = dboMVI
    .Where(mvi=> (mvi.Code == 'MyName' && 
        nums.Any(n=> n.Contains(mvi.ColNumber))) &&
        (mvi.Code == 'MyName' && 
           disp.Any(d=> d.Contains(mvi.Display)))
    .OrderBy(x=>x.RowNumber)
    .Select(x=>.RowNumber);
```

As you can see, both conditions have to be meet to return data.

**[EDIT#2]**

As to the Expression... i think it should look like this:

```
Expression<Func<ViewItem, string, int, string, bool>> filter = (mvi, code, colNo, disp) => 
        dboMVI.Any(innerMvi =>
            innerMvi.RowNumber == mvi.RowNumber  &&
            innerMvi.Code==code && 
            innerMvi.ColNumber == colNo && 
            innerMvi.Display == disp);
```

**[Finall note]**

Note: i can't access to your data and i'm not able to guarantee for 100% that above query will meet your criteria.

Comment: Thx for your fast comment, that part that u were wondering it was typing mistake. Its should be fixed in orginal thread now. all is innerMvi.Display. I wll check tomorrow this tuned up sql query:)

Comment: I checked this query and it's not resolving my issue, first of all it's selecting all rows witch match for any of this conditions while i need to get only thous that match both of it.
Second it's not allowing me for easy manipulation between fiters type. I mean in some cases it's filed hs to be equal in other it has to contain or not equal. In exists query it's much easier to accomplish this task. But thanks anyway your answer can be very usuefull in future in other kind of querys.

Comment: I added extra info to my answer. Please, check it out.

Comment: Still it does not return correct data, Im not sure but prop its trying to match any from Col_Number 1 to "UserName" and same for Col_Number 3 while i need to get only UserName from Col_Number 1 and only "2261" from Col_Number 3. There can be value "UserName" in Col_Number 3 and i dont want this record.